# Error saving e-mail from outlook via Python win32com.client: Unable to write to file

Tags: python, file-io, outlook, win32com

I am trying to save mail via Python and get this error

> -2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Unable to write to file: C:\...\ docs. Right-click the folder containing the file you want to write to, and then select 'Properties' from the menu and check your permissions for this folder.'

Account has all the permissions and access to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show your code. Make sure you pass a fully qualified file name that includes **both** the path **and** the file name, not just a path or a file name.  It looks like you are only passing the path (C:\docs).

Answer (score 0):

The system drive `C:\` requires admin privileges for writing. Try choosing another drive or folder.